# Abort() error loading bitmap Allegro 5

Tags: c, pointers, memory, allocation, allegro

Have this textbox.png been using while working on game. It always used to load with al_load_bitmap() but now the code breaks after running 10 seconds before even reaching the part that draws the bitmap. Clicking break and retry after the error message takes you to lines of  code relating to the bitmap, hovering over the error shows the bitmap not loaded (0x000000000 NULL). Can memory leaks cause this? Sometimes the bitmap loads then when switching gamestates real fast it gives error. 
Edit:: have also tried switching directories and png files to no avail

Comment: This could be a lot of things. If you provide a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) it will be much easier to determine your issue.

Comment: Always check for NULL pointer in your code. The usual cause of this is that you think you have the correct path to the bitmap but it isn't. It used to work where? Inside the IDE or by clicking on the program directly?